# Complex parameter not getting to web api server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I am trying a put operation from my mvc project, to a web api. I have two parameters one an integer type the other one is a complex type each time I make 
a call to the server
the simple type gets to the server while the complex type is null. It works fine from postman... Please I need to know what i'm doing wrong

Here is my model

```
//Same with client side
public class PaymentTypeVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my client side code

```
    public static async Task<RequestResult> EditPaymentType<T>(int id, T model)
    {

        var content = new { Model = model };

        var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);


        var resp = await _client.PutAsync($"api/admin/editpaymenttype/{id}", new StringContent(str, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));

        var txt = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestResult>(txt);
    }
```

Here is the server code

```
    [HttpPut]
    [Route("editpaymenttype/{id}")]
    public async Task<RequestResult> EditPaymentType(int id, [FromBody]PaymentTypeVM model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return RequestResult.FailureResult(Messages.InvalidEntry);
        }

        var pType = await db.PaymentTypes.FindAsync(id);

        if (pType == null) return RequestResult.FailureResult(Messages.NotFound);            

        pType.Name = model.Name ?? pType.Name;

        await db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RequestResult.SuccessResult($"Payment type {Messages.EditSuccessful}");
    }
```

Please I need a simplified answer cos i'm a novice, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you call `EditPaymentType` like this: `EditPaymentType<PaymentTypeVM>`

Change this part in the client...

```
var content = new { Model = model };
var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
```

to this...

```
var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
```

You're currently sending it a serialized object that has a property of `Model`, with the value being your model, but then trying to map it to a parameter of type `PaymentTypeVM` when it's deserialized on the server.

If the types don't match then it can't deserialize the body contents into the parameter, and it ends up being null.

Answer (score 1):

You should change it.

```
var content = new { Model = model };

var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(content);
```

to

```
var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model);
```

Don't send the `model` as nested object.

Comment: Thanks Stormcloak. I am very greatful

Answer (score 0):

the `HttpClient` sends a parameter with this structure:

```
{
    Model =
    {
        Id = 1,
        Name = "Name"
    }
}
```

while, the `WebApi` server expects a parameter like this:

```
{
    Id = 1,
    Name = "Name"
}
```